# Inheriting 'NamedTuple', which is not a class.pylint(inherit-non-class)

Tags: python, pylint, linter

I am trying to declare tokens with unique value in python:

```
from enum import (
  auto,
  Enum,
  unique
)

from typing import NamedTuple

@unique
class TokenType(Enum):
  ASSIGN = auto()
  COMMA = auto()
  EOF = auto()
  FUNCTION = auto()
  IDENT = auto()
  ILLEGAL = auto()
  INT = auto()
  LBRACE = auto()
  LET = auto()
  LPAREN = auto()
  PLUS = auto()
  RBRACE = auto()
  RPAREN = auto()
  SEMICOLON = auto()

class Token(NamedTuple):
  token_type: TokenType
  literal: str

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'Type: {self.token_type}, Literal: {self.literal}'
```

but I am getting this pylint error:

> Inheriting 'NamedTuple', which is not a class.pylint(inherit-non-class)

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: This is an open issue in Pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3876

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see, then I need to downgrade Python version if I want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments:

> This is an open issue in Pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3876

The issue was fixed in the upstream project astroid.
I could fix this problem by upgrading:

```
pip install astroid==2.5
```